# Using ALIAS for Table Name have any performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have two tables

```
Table : Department 
Columns 
1) DeptID 
2) DeptName

Table : Employee 
Columns 
1) EmpID
2) EmpName
3) DeptID
```

When I apply join on these two tables, I have to use `Employee.DeptID = Department.DeptID`

Now I restructure my table design and now my table will look like below:

```
Table : Department 
Columns 
1) DeptID 
2) DeptName

Table : Employee 
Columns 
1) EmpID
2) EmpName
3) Emp_DeptID
```

Now with these column names I dont have to use ALIAS, I can simply use `DeptID = Emp_DeptID`

My question is, using ALIAS hampers query performance in anyway??

Comment: Nope -- it defines which table to reference the column from.  There is no performance difference in the two.  Column naming conventions are a completely different question/debate however...

Comment: Does it means alias has no impact on query performance? It is only for better readability.

Comment: Without the table names (not aliases, see my long-winded answer below) I would say the query is *less* readable, not more.  It's certainly less robust, as adding a column to either table with the wrong name could break the query.

Comment: As per your answer Larry, I use Example 1 because I dont have to use alias, it is just coding standard I follow to avoid ambiguity of column names while using JOIN. Whether it improves query performance is what i want to know?

Comment: Pssst: when you need to join to the same table twice, you need to use an alias regardless. Making column names unique across the database isn't really that helpful! Consider `SELECT T1.TColumn, T2.TColumn FROM TBL AS T1 INNER JOIN TBL AS T2 ON T1.TParent = T2.TID`. You need to use an alias here

Comment: The right way to approach performance (in SQL Server, but everywhere else, for that matter) is to set performance *goals*, and then ignore them and **write simple, clear, code that does the job**. Then *measure* the performance of that code and compare it against the goals. If it meets the goals, great, job done and move on to the next task. If not, you need to measure *where* the performance issue is and then work out how to address that issue. I pretty well 100% guarantee it will not come down to column naming and the use (or not) of aliases.

Comment: If you want to know if the use of aliases impacts the performance of the query (I'm 100% sure that it doesn't), just measure the execution of the queries with and without the aliases. Moreover, do you have any evidence/proof about a possible performance impact? The fact that you don't have to use aliases in 2nd example it doesn't mean there's a performance bottleneck. Anyway the strategy is: Set a performance goal, write the code, measure its performance and check the results. I didn't read any record or anything else in literature about performance differences in using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, neither example in your question uses aliases.

Consider the following fragments:

```
1. FROM Department, Employee WHERE DeptID = emp_DeptID

2. FROM Department, Employee WHERE Department.DeptID = Employee.emp_DeptID

3. FROM Department AS D, Employee AS E WHERE D.DeptID = E.emp_DeptID
```

Example #3 uses aliases.  Aliases are used to assign a temporary alternate name to a relation in a query.  They are used for two reasons: 1) to reduce typing and improve clarity when a table name must be typed many times and 2) to disambiguate when the same relation is used more than once in the query (in a self-join or correlate sub-query, for instance).

Example 2 simply uses fully-qualified column names but those are not table aliases.

Example 1 is something I have to admit is new to me; the idea that if the column names in the JOIN conditions are unambiguously available from only one relation you don't need to qualify them with the relation name.  After decades of *always* qualifying join conditions that feels "wrong" to me.  The danger is that you might, in the future, add an identically named column into one of the relations causing the query to fail (or worse, return incorrect results).  But I admit to not always qualifying the column names in the selected column list and that suffers from the same danger, so I think I'm just speaking from force of habit.

Oh, and to answer your original question: fully qualifying by including the table names will probably have a tiny positive effect on the query analyzer (which converts your SQL into an executable query plan).  That's because you're not forcing the analyzer to do the qualification for you.  But that effect will likely be too small to measure compared to the time taken to actually perform the query.

Comment: Whether alias have any performance issues? Whether it slows query performance?